# Add (not merge!) two data frames with unequal rows and columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to efficiently sum the entries of two data frames, though the data frames are not guaranteed to have the same dimensions or column names. Merge isn't really what I'm after here. Instead I want to create an output object with all of the row and column names that belong to either of the added data frames. In each position of that output, I want to use the following logic for the computed value:

- If a row/column pairing belongs to both input data frames I want the output to include their sum
- If a row/column pairing belongs to just one input data frame I want to include that value in the output
- If a row/column pairing does not belong to any input matrix I want to have 0 in that position in the output.

As an example, consider the following input data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,5,6))
rownames(df1) = c("a", "b", "c")
df2 = data.frame(x = c(7,8), z = c(9,10), w = c(2, 3))
rownames(df2) = c("a", "d")
> df1
  x y
a 1 4
b 2 5
c 3 6
> df2
  x  z  w 
a 7  9  2
d 8 10  3
```

I want the final result to be

```
> df2
   x  y   z  w
a  8  4   9  2
b  2  5   0  0
c  3  6   0  0
d  8  0  10  3
```

What I've done so far -

bind_rows / bind_cols in dplyr can throw the following:
 "Error: incompatible number of rows (3, expecting 2)"

I have duplicated column names, so 'merge' isn't working for my purposes either - returns an empty df for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you could merge on the rownames, then take care of the sums and conversion of `NA` to zero with some additional munging:

```
library(dplyr)

df.new = df1 %>% add_rownames %>%
  full_join(df2 %>% add_rownames, by="rowname") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), 0))) %>%
  mutate(x = x.x + x.y) %>%
  select(rowname,x,y,z,w)
```

Or, with @DavidArenburg's much more elegant and extensible solution:

```
df.new = df1 %>% add_rownames %>% 
  full_join(df2 %>% add_rownames) %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))

df.new

  rowname     x     y     z     w
1       a     8     4     9     2
2       b     2     5     0     0
3       c     3     6     0     0
4       d     8     0    10     3
```

Comment: Well, @DavidArenburg really deserves the credit, as I was making this much more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like some type of a simple merge on common column names (+ row names) and then a simple aggregation, this is how I would tackle this

```
library(data.table)
merge(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), # Convert to data.table + keep rows
      setDT(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE), # Convert to data.table + keep rows
      by = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), # merge on common column names
      all = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn] # Sum all columns by group                   
#    rn x y  z w
# 1:  a 8 4  9 2
# 2:  b 2 5  0 0
# 3:  c 3 6  0 0
# 4:  d 8 0 10 3
```

---

Are a pretty straight forward base R solution

```
df1$rn <- row.names(df1)
df2$rn <- row.names(df2)
res <- merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
rowsum(res[setdiff(names(res), "rn")], res[, "rn"], na.rm = TRUE)
#   x y  z w
# a 8 4  9 2
# b 2 5  0 0
# c 3 6  0 0
# d 8 0 10 3
```

Comment: Very nifty. I forgot about the all = TRUE argument in `merge`.

Comment: `merge` will by default use the `intersect`ion of the names of each dataset. You can leave `by=` blank and get the same result.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah I forgot it's the default in base. In `data.table` it won't work if you haven't set the keys.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would grab the names of all the rows and columns of the new entity:

```
(all.rows <- unique(c(row.names(df1), row.names(df2))))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
(all.cols <- unique(c(names(df1), names(df2))))
# [1] "x" "y" "z" "w"
```

Then I would construct an output matrix with those rows and column names (with matrix data initialized to all 0s), adding `df1` and `df2` to the relevant parts of that matrix.

```
out <- matrix(0, nrow=length(all.rows), ncol=length(all.cols))
rownames(out) <- all.rows
colnames(out) <- all.cols
out[row.names(df1),names(df1)] <- unlist(df1)
out[row.names(df2),names(df2)] <- out[row.names(df2),names(df2)] + unlist(df2)
out
#   x y  z w
# a 8 4  9 2
# b 2 5  0 0
# c 3 6  0 0
# d 8 0 10 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I prefer this solution to eipi10's because this doesn't require a renaming, which I would need to do dynamically. While I normally prefer dplyr, this solution makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xtabs` on melted / stacked data frames:

```
out <- rbind(cbind(rn=rownames(df1),stack(df1)), cbind(rn=rownames(df2),stack(df2)))
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(values ~ rn + ind, data=out))

#  x y w  z
#a 8 4 2  9
#b 2 5 0  0
#c 3 6 0  0
#d 8 0 3 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not convinced the accepted (or alternative merge) method is the best. It will give incorrect results if you have common rows, they’ll get joined and not summed.

This can be shown trivialy by changing df2 to:

```
df2 = data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c(4,5), z = c(9,10), w = c(2, 3))
rownames(df2) = c("a", "d")
```

expected results:

```
   rn x y  z w
1:  a 2 8  9 2
2:  b 2 5  0 0
3:  c 3 6  0 0
4:  d 2 5 10 3
```

actual results

```
merge(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
  setDT(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
  by = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)), 
  all = TRUE)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]

   rn x y  z w
1:  a 1 4  9 2
2:  b 2 5  0 0
3:  c 3 6  0 0
4:  d 2 5 10 3
```

You need to combine both the outer join with an inner join (or left/right joins, merge all=T/all=F).  Or alternatively using plyr’s rbind.fill :

base R solution

```
res <- rbind.fill(df1,df2)
rowsum(res[setdiff(names(res), "rn")], res[, "rn"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

data table solution

```
as.data.table(rbind.fill(
  setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE),
  setDT(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE)
))[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = rn]
```

I prefer the rbind.fill method as you can "merge" > 2 data frames using the same syntax.