# How to merge data frame and a string

Tags: r

In the case that a=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2) and b=c('name',3). I am trying to merge a and b  such that the outcome is [1 3 name 3] in the first row and [2 4]  in the second row.

Comment: (1) `cbind` gives you the first row. (2) A `data.frame` always has the same number elements in each column. Period. Would it be better to have `NA` in the second row, columns 3-4?

Comment: cbind is also repeating [name 3] for both the rows,

Comment: Yes, see my note 2. I suspect there's a misunderstanding of R's `data.frame`s here. Perhaps you can create (manually) a `data.frame` that should be the result of your programmatic merging? At the moment, this question is unclear, perhaps due to miscommunication or misunderstanding of R data structures.

Comment: In the case that a=matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2) and b=c('name',3). I am trying to merge a and b such that the outcome is [1 3 name 3] in the first row and [2 4] in the second row.

Comment: And that's my point: it cannot be done, because that defies what a `data.frame` *is*. A matrix and a `data.frame` are similar in that they must be rectangular, with *something* in each cell. That "something" might be an `NA` which could indicate "nothing" or "could be anything", but it is something. Is there a programming language where the frame/matrix allows `[[1,2,'name',3],[3,4]]` as a matrix/dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows differs in each dataframe. Therefore cbind is going to have a hard time merging the data and will by default loop the shorter dataframe, in this case b.
I would suggest adding in the rowname as a column and then binding on that. By default, full_join will then generate NA values for dataframes missing that value of the bind. This question is partially a duplicate of [Add (not merge!) two data frames with unequal rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162993/add-not-merge-two-data-frames-with-unequal-rows-and-columns) so you may find more help there.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr) # To use the inplace assignment operator (%<>%) 

# Create dataframes
a <- data.frame(1:2,3:4)
b <- merge('name', 3)

# Create rowname column for each dataframe
a %<>% tibble::rownames_to_column()
b %<>% tibble::rownames_to_column()

# Use 'full join' to bind dataframes together
c <- dplyr::full_join(a, b, by=rowname) %>%
       # Remove the rowname column
       dplyr::select(-rowname)

# Print c
print(c)
  X1.2 X3.4    x  y
  1    1    3 name  3
  2    2    4 <NA> NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are satisfied with a list, not data frame, this will work.

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)
b <- c('name',3)
c <- list(a[,1],a[,2],b[1],b[2] )
```

If you need a data frame,
you have to make the 1st and 2nd row have the same number of columns, by stuffing the gaps with something.

```
d <- as.data.frame(c)
d[2,3:4] <- NA
```

Comment: This will result in [ 1 3 name 3] in first row and [2 4 <NA> <NA> ] in the second row. Can we remove <NA> from the second row and get  it only  [2 4    ]. I tried with  replace(d,d[2,3:4], " " ); but got an error as it only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables.

Comment: In the R's data frame, each column must have the same length of elements. Thus it is not possible to create what you want. Why do you need that type of data? You have to do ad hoc data manipulations when you use the data frame, keeping NA in the data frame. Or create and use data in a list format.